# LLBLGen Pro Unboxing Error With Decimal Fields

Tags: .net, oracle, llblgen

We're using LLBLGen Pro to create an ORM between our application and an Oracle 11 database. The problem we're having is that it is generating .NET decimal-type fields for Oracle table columns that are of type NUMBER(10, 0). I would have expected a number like this to be exposed as an integer type.

The end result is that on using the ORM, we're getting casting/unboxing errors when LLBLGen tries to save or update an entity.

Can anyone out there shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post on our support forums (http://www.llblgen.com/tinyforum) so our support team can pick it up.

As you haven't given the version you're using, nor the oracle ADO.NET provider you're using (ODP.NET or MS Oracle), I can't help you further other than giving some general information:

As ODP.NET returns a NUMBER(10, 0) as long, I think you're using MS Oracle. MS Oracle (the .NET oracle provider) returns all NUMBER types as decimal. If you don't want that, use ODP.NET

The cast issue is weird, it should work properly. But as said, please post on our forums as we don't regularly monitor stackoverflow for llblgen related issues. Thanks.

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot, we were using MS Oracle when generating the DAL. Switched to ODP.Net and the types are generating correctly.